# Legends on graphs

Tags: c++, plot, legend

I am new to using C++, and I have been trying to plot some basic graphs that include legends in them. I have been googling to find ways to do this, and found that chplot.h can do this, like in the link below:

http://www.softintegration.com/docs/ch/plot/

I want to download this header file online, but can't seem to find it. Is there a website that can do this? Or is there another header file that allows you to plot a legend on a graph?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

A header file itself will most likely not allow you to do anything. You'd need the whole library (Ch professional in this case) for that. Have you read through the site you link to?

Anyway, they say they're based on [GNUplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/), so you might want to investigate that.

On the other hand, if you want to learn C++ rather than just use it for one particular task, there are easier and better suited problems to start with.